# python csv format all rows to one line

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

Ive a csv file that I would like to get all the rows in one column. Ive tried importing into MS Excel or Formatting it with Notedpad++ . However with each try it considers a piece of data as a new row.
How can I format file with pythons csv module so that it removes a string "BRAS" and corrects the format. Each row is found between a quote " and delimiter is a pipe |.
Update:

```
 "aa|bb|cc|dd|
 ee|ff"
 "ba|bc|bd|be|
 bf"
 "ca|cb|cd|
 ce|cf"
```

The above is supposed to be 3 rows, however my editors see them as 5 rows or 6 and so forth.

```
import csv
import fileinput


with open('ventoya.csv') as f, open('ventoya2.csv', 'w') as w:
    for line in f:
        if 'BRAS' not in line:
            w.write(line)
```

N.B I get a unicode error when trying to use in python.

```
 return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 18: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Okay did an update hope that gives a clearer idea.

Comment: Yes its consistent as every row  breaks at a particular column.

Comment: This is not a comma separated values (CSV) file, but a delimited file. If the line breaks are not significant you can remove them using search and replace in for example Microsoft Word using the formatting option. You need to read the file using a function where you specify the delimiter as `|`, otherwise you can search and replace `|` with `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick hack for small input files (the content is read to memory).

```
#!python2

fnameIn = 'ventoya.csv'
fnameOut = 'ventoya2.csv'
with open(fnameIn) as fin, open(fnameOut, 'w') as fout:
    data = fin.read()              # content of the input file
    data = data.replace('\n', '')  # make it one line
    data = data.replace('""', '|') # split char instead of doubled ""
    data = data.replace('"', '')   # remove the first and last "
    print data
    for x in data.split('|'):      # split by bar
        fout.write(x + '\n')       # write to separate lines
```

Or if the goal is only to fix the extra (unwanted) newline to form a single-column CSV file, the file can be fixed first, and then read through the csv module:

```
#!python2
import csv

fnameIn = 'ventoya.csv'
fnameFixed = 'ventoyaFixed.csv'
fnameOut = 'ventoya2.csv'

# Fix the input file.
with open(fnameIn) as fin, open(fnameFixed, 'w') as fout:
    data = fin.read()                   # content of the file
    data = data.replace('\n', '')       # remove the newlines
    data = data.replace('""', '"\n"')   # add the newlines back between the cells
    fout.write(data)

# It is an overkill, but now the fixed file can be read using
# the csv module.
with open(fnameFixed, 'rb') as fin, open(fnameOut, 'wb') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks so much each time I get stuck on a unicode error. "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 18: character maps to <undefined>" . What next should I be looking at and attempt to do ?

Comment: What version of Python do you use? What encoding the file uses? You should reflect it when opening the file. In Python 3, you should pass the encoding='xxx', in Python 2 it is done differently. In this case, you probably use Python 3.

Comment: After reading I got to discover that so I stepped down to python 2. One other thing I forgot to mention is that the original code has some HTML hence also has " in between.  The original coding is UTF-8.

Comment: In Python 2, it is even more difficult if you want to use unicode strings. I suggest to use Python 3. Actually, it is cleaner and easier. However, the csv module have to be used with different arguments because the files must be open in the text mode.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this you need not to go to even code. 
1: Just open file in Notepad++
2: In first line select from | symble till next line
3: go to replace and replace the selected format with |

Search mode can be normal or extended :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the line breaks are consistent, you could go in and do find/replace as suggested, but you could also do a quick conversion with your python script:

```
import csv
import fileinput

linecount = 0
with open('ventoya.csv') as f, open('ventoya2.csv', 'w') as w:
    for line in f: 
        line = line.rstrip()

# remove unwanted breaks by concatenating pairs of rows            

        if linecount%2 == 0:
            line1 = line
        else:
            full_line = line1 + line

            full_line = full_line.replace(' ','')
# remove spaces from front of 2nd half of line

# if you want comma delimiters, uncomment next line:
#           full_line = full_line.replace('|',',')

        if 'BRAS' not in full_line:
            w.write(full_line + '\n')
    linecount += 1
```

This works for me with the test data, and if you want to change the delimiters while writing to file, you can. The nice thing about doing with code is: 1. you can do it with code (always fun) and 2. you can remove the line breaks and filter content to the written file at the same time.

Comment: Thanks getting the same unicode error "
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 18: character maps to <undefined"